# How can I deal with "The user-provided path C:/Users/Libraries does not exist." below while copying object from computer to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am getting the below error. It gets executed properly when I go through my /Downloads directory, but it shows The user-provided path  does not exist. Even though it is exact with only changing the folder name exactly as it is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uibzZ.png)

Comment: What exactly is the question?  The error says "C:/Users/Libraries/Music/Sample_Music" doesn't exist.  Does that directory exist?

Answer (score 1):

This is from the S3 documentation:

Single Local File and S3 Object Operations
Some commands perform operations only on single files and S3 objects. **The following commands are single file/object operations if no --recursive flag is provided.**

cp
mv
rm

Try the --recursive flag if you've several files in that directory. Append it at the end of the string command.